# How to separate (split) string with comma in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a `checkboxlist`. The selected (checked) items are stored in `List<string> selected`.

For example, value selected is `monday,tuesday,thursday` out of 7 days

I am converting `List<>` to a comma-separated `string`, i.e.

```
string a= "monday,tuesday,thursday"
```

Now, I am passing this value to a stored procedure as a string. I want to fire query like:

```
Select * 
from tblx 
where days = 'Monday' or days = 'Tuesday' or days = 'Thursday'`
```

My question is: how to separate string in the stored procedure?

Comment: You don't have to separate strings in proc, instead you can use `IN`. If you are looking to split values then create a function based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10581814/961113) and then use it

Comment: What if instead of OR we had to use AND i.e
WHERE days = 'Monday' AND days = 'Tuesday'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you pass the comma separated (any separator) string to store procedure and use in query so must need to spit that string and then you will use it.

Below have example:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(500) = 'monday,tuesday,thursday'
CREATE TABLE #Temp (tDay VARCHAR(100))
WHILE LEN(@str) > 0
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TDay VARCHAR(100)
    IF CHARINDEX(',',@str) > 0
        SET  @TDay = SUBSTRING(@str,0,CHARINDEX(',',@str))
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET  @TDay = @str
        SET @str = ''
        END
  INSERT INTO  #Temp VALUES (@TDay)
 SET @str = REPLACE(@str,@TDay + ',' , '')
 END

 SELECT * 
 FROM tblx 
 WHERE days IN (SELECT tDay FROM #Temp)
```

Comment: Use dbo.ufnSplit function that I answered is better and clear code on store procedure.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnSplit] (@string NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS @parsedString TABLE (id NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS 
BEGIN
   DECLARE @separator NCHAR(1)
   SET @separator=','
   DECLARE @position int
   SET @position = 1
   SET @string = @string + @separator
   WHILE charindex(@separator,@string,@position) <> 0
      BEGIN
         INSERT into @parsedString
         SELECT substring(@string, @position, charindex(@separator,@string,@position) - @position)
         SET @position = charindex(@separator,@string,@position) + 1
      END
     RETURN
END
```

Then use this function,

```
Select * 
from tblx 
where days IN (SELECT id FROM [dbo].[ufnSplit]('monday,tuesday,thursday'))
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split
(
  @delimited nvarchar(max),
  @delimiter nvarchar(100)
) RETURNS @t TABLE
(
-- Id column can be commented out, not required for sql splitting string
  id int identity(1,1), -- I use this column for numbering splitted parts
  val nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
  declare @xml xml
  set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

  insert into @t(val)
  select
    r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
  from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

  RETURN
END
GO
```

usage:

```
select * from tblx where days in (select val from dbo.split('monday,tuesday,thursday',','))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
SELECT * FROM tblx where days in ('Monday','Tuesday','Thursday')
```

you can get it like this:

```
var a = "monday,tuesday,thursday";
var sql = string.Format("Select * from tblx where days IN ('{0}')", string.Join("','",a.Split(new[] {','})));
```

Comment: thanks for response,,but sir,,what if user selects tuesday and wednesday from that checkboxlist

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem, and i try all the way but not get expected solution. Finally i did like follow. Try it hope it will work...

```
create Function [dbo].[Split]
(
   @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5)
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
   Data NVARCHAR(100)
)
AS
BEGIN 
   DECLARE @Cnt INT
   SET @Cnt = 1
   WHILE (Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)>0)
   BEGIN
          INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
          SELECT Data = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@RowData,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)-1)))
          SET @RowData = Substring(@RowData,Charindex(@SplitOn,@RowData)+1,len(@RowData))
          SET @Cnt = @Cnt + 1
   END
   INSERT INTO @RtnValue (data)
   SELECT Data = ltrim(rtrim(@RowData))
   RETURN
END
```

And in the store procedure put the code like that.

```
select @ActualTarget= count(*) from UpdateVisitDetails where CreatedBy IN (SELECT [DATA] FROM [dbo].[Split](@AllDATS,',' ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. I tried this.. and this was properly run

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split]
(
  @List varchar(max),
  @SplitOn nvarchar(5)
)

RETURNS @RtnValue table
(
  Id int identity(1,1),
  Value nvarchar(max)
)
AS
BEGIN
IF (len(@List) <=0)
Begin
Return 
End

While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
Begin

Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
Select
Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1)))

Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
End

Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))

Return
END

Run : 
SELECT * FROM dbo.Split('Apple,Banana,Mango',',')
```

**Output:**

[image]