# Need a solution for SQL query where reference column have different datatype

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I need column-2 data of table-2 through the column-1 of table-1 
**Ex**. if table-1(column-1) have 1,2,4 then output should be email1@email.com,email2@email.com,email4@email.com

---

**Table -1**       **Table -2**
**Column-1**      **Column-1**    **Column-2**
***(varchar)***    ***(int)***     ***(varchar)***
1,2,4          1      email1@email.com
2,3           2      email2@email.com
              3      email3@email.com
          4      email4@email.com

---

Using join I tried casting but doesn't work.
Tried Query :

```
SELECT *
FROM Table-1
join Table-2
    on Table-1.Column-1 LIKE '%'+ cast(Table-2.Column-1 as varchar(MAX))+'%'
```

Comment: which db and what error you are getting

Comment: sql server , error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ CAST(Table-2.Column-1 AS varchar(MAX)) +'%' LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: If it is MYSQL replace `max` with, say, 10.

Comment: Don't store lists of integers as comma separated strings. It's a breach of database design.  It becomes harder to maintain the data, reduces performance, makes queries more complex and likely to break, prevents integrity constraints such as foreign keys, prevents tools such as indexes from being useful.  Fix the problem (the design), not the symptom (how to write the join).

Answer (score 1):

first you should separate `Column-1` from `Table-1` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23089579/how-to-separate-split-string-with-comma-in-sql-server-stored-procedure)
then join tables like `Table-1 join Table-2 on Table-1.Column-1=Table-2.separatedItem`

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast  as a `char` datatype, there is no `varchar` datatype that you can use in cast

MySQL supports limited data type for  CAST, you can read more about the suppprted data types [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Try like following query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
`Table-1` t1
inner join  `Table-2` t2 on t1.`Column-1` LIKE 
                CONCAT('%', cast(t2.`Column-1` as char(100)),'%')
```

Comment: @MatBailie can you have a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/q/15368753/297322

Comment: @MatBailie even it is not mentioned in the docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast